# i want to write looping dataframe to excel

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

1.I am new to python.this task for mainly read the excel files in directory and filter the data in excel. After filtering write into excel.When iam trying to write to excel its storing only last iteration values.Please give advise to write all data to excel . I want to write **df_filter** and **df_filter1** to excel which is for loop .Please help me  **i need to write these dataframe to excell**

```
import os
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
import xlwt
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import xlsxwriter
from pyexcelerate import Workbook
import numpy as np
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
ALL_SHEETS = []
sheet_list = ""
file_path = os.path.join(input("enter Dir path"))
config_path = os.path.join(input("enter your config file path here"))
output_path = os.path.join(input("Dude where you want store outputfile"))

output1 = pd.ExcelWriter(output_path, engine='xlsxwriter')



ALL_SHEETS = [os.path.join(file_path, f) for f in os.listdir(file_path)
              if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(file_path, f))
              and f.endswith('.xlsx')]

i = 0
data1 = []
data = []
Packet_size = []
Trail_numbers = []
Though_put = []
Latency = []
Jitter = []

df_filter  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['packetsize',  'throughput', 'latency (us)', 'jitter (us)'])
df_filter1  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['packetsize', 'throughput', 'latency (us)', 'jitter (us)'])
#df_sheet = pd.DataFrame(columns=['zsheet'])
merged_inner=pd.DataFrame([])


def sheets(val):

    s = wb.worksheets[val]
    df_sheet = pd.DataFrame( data=['%s' % str(s) + '\n'])
    #Name_sheet(s)

    HeaderList = pd.read_csv(config_path)

    column_list = []
    for col in HeaderList:
        col = col.lstrip("'")
        col = col.rstrip("'")
        column_list.append(col)

    df1 = xl.parse(sheet_list[val], skiprows=i)
    df1 = df1.filter(column_list)

    df2 = df1[(df1['Result'] != 'Failed') & (df1['Frame Size Type'] == 'iMIX')]

    if df2.empty:
        pass
    else:
        final3= df2.groupby(['Trial Number', 'iMIX Distribution'], sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Throughput (%)'].idxmax()])
        #df_filter['sheetaname']=df_sheet(lambda a:'%s' % a['sheetvise'],axis=1)
        final = final3.groupby(['iMIX Distribution'], sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Throughput (%)'].idxmax()])
        df_filter['packetsize'] = final.apply(lambda z: '%s' % (z['iMIX Distribution']), axis=1)


        df_filter['throughput'] = final.apply(lambda z: '%s' % (z['Throughput (%)']), axis=1)
        df_filter['latency (us)'] = final.apply(lambda x: '%s/%s/%s' % (x['Minimum Latency (us)'], x['Maximum Latency (us)'], x['Average Latency (us)']),axis=1)
        df_filter['jitter (us)'] = final.apply(lambda y: '%s/%s/%s' % (y['Minimum Jitter (us)'], y['Maximum Jitter (us)'], y['Average Jitter (us)']),axis=1)


        df_filter.to_excel(output1,sheet_name='mani')
        output1.save()
        df_filter.to_excel(output1, startrow=len(df_filter1)+len(df_filter)+2,sheet_name='mani')
        output1.save()


    df3 = df1[(df1['Result'] != 'Failed') & (df1['Frame Size Type'] == 'Fixed')]
    if df3.empty:
        pass
    else:
        final2 = df3.groupby(['Trial Number', 'Configured Frame Size'], sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Throughput (%)'].idxmax()])
        final1=final2.groupby(['Configured Frame Size'],sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Throughput (%)'].idxmax()])


        df_filter1['packetsize'] = final1.apply(lambda z: '%s' % (z['Configured Frame Size']), axis=1)

        df_filter1['throughput'] = final1.apply(lambda z: '%s' % (z['Throughput (%)']), axis=1)
        df_filter1['latency (us)'] = final1.apply(lambda x: '%s/%s/%s' % (x['Minimum Latency (us)'], x['Maximum Latency (us)'], x['Average Latency (us)']),axis=1)
        df_filter1['jitter (us)'] = final1.apply(lambda y: '%s/%s/%s' % (y['Minimum Jitter (us)'], y['Maximum Jitter (us)'], y['Average Jitter (us)']),axis=1)


        df_filter1.to_excel(output1, sheet_name='mani')

        df_filter1.to_excel(output1, startrow=len(df_filter1)+len(df_filter) + 2, sheet_name='mani')
        output1.save()
def sheet_every():


    for sheet in range(0, sheet_list_lenght):
        sheets(sheet)




for file in (ALL_SHEETS):


    df_file = pd.DataFrame(data=[file])

    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
    wb = load_workbook(file)


    xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    i = 0

    sheet_list = workbook.sheet_names()
    sheet_list_lenght = (len(sheet_list))
    for sheet in sheet_list:
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet)

        for i in range(0, worksheet.nrows):
            row = worksheet.row_values(i)
            if 'Trial Number' in row:``


                break

    sheet_every()
```

Comment: do any one understood my question

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question or not, but if you want to read from a dataframe and add rows to a new dataframe thorugh a loop you can refer the code below:

```
dummyData = pd.read_csv("someexcelfile.csv")
#You can merge mutiple dataframes into dummyData and make it a big dataframe
dummyInsertTable = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Col1","Col2","Col3"])

for i in range(len(dummyData)):
   dummyInsertTable.loc[i,"Col1"] = dummyData["Col1"][i]
   dummyInsertTable.loc[i, "Col2"] = dummyData["Col2"][i]
   dummyInsertTable.loc[i, "Col3"] = dummyData["Col3"][i]
dummyInsertTable.to_csv("writeCSVFile.csv")
```

And next time be precise where you are facing the problem.

**EDIT**
Try loading the first dataframe and then loop through the other files and append the files in the first dataframe. Refer the code:

```
import pandas as pd
#Make a list of all the file you have 
filesList = ["/home/bhushan/firstFile.csv","/home/bhushan/secondFile.csv","/home/bhushan/thirdFile.csv","/home/bhushan/fourthFile.csv"]

#Read the first csv file using pandas.read_csv
firstFile = pd.read_csv(filesList[0])

#Loop through the rest of the files and append the files in the first DataFrame
for i in range(1,len(filesList)):
    fileToBeAdded = pd.read_csv(filesList[i])
    firstFile = firstFile.append(fileToBeAdded)

#Write the final file
finalFile = firstFile
finalFile.to_csv("finalFile.csv")
```

Comment: Hi ,I dont want to store rows of one dataframe to another.  I want to write dataframe(df_filter,df_filter1) to excel in loop.

Comment: So, if I am understanding your question correctly you want to merge multiple data frames and write the merged file to excel?

Comment: exactly @Bhushan pant

Comment: Then use pandas.merge function or pandas.append. Note: Column names should be same in all the data frames.

Comment: i have tried merge .but i was written only last iteration

Comment: above your code not working for my code.Could you please give me another idea

Comment: @Ram I have edited my answer. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, you have two data frames which you want to write to one excel file but you are only getting the last one. 
You should write them to two different sheets instead, then you can retrieve them as per requirement, either individually or combined.
Follow the below links for more details and implementation :
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html
https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/importing-managing-financial-data-in-python/importing-stock-listing-data-from-excel?ex=11

Also, you can instead write to a csv file, that is also excel compatible and easier to handle. Also I have observed that it is faster and more space efficient compared to writing to .xlsx file.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html